# How to force one AJAX request to wait to finish for another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm working on a game that uses a lot of AJAX calls to update, save, edit save games, etc.

Thing is that it seems that subsequently started AJAX requests do not queue up like I want to.

For example I'm checking server side if an action is allowed, so I need a current save game. The save game is sent before, but the check request executes before the save game request finished.

So I want it so be like this:

```
AJAX start: Save Game
AJAX finish: Save Game
AJAX start: Check
AJAX finish: Check
AJAX start: Save Game
AJAX finish: Save Game
```

Currently it's more like this:

```
AJAX start: Save Game
AJAX start: Check
AJAX finish: Save Game
AJAX start: Save Game
AJAX finish: Check
AJAX finish: Save Game
```

Even though timewise the AJAX calls are triggered in correct order. They just would need to wait until the previous triggered call finished.

Is there a way to achieve this globally? Because the thing is that most calls don't know about the other requests.

Can I get this done without `setInterval` calls to check if a requests finished?

**UPDATE:** Obviously, I didn't cleared out the actual problem. I know that this is because AJAX is async.

But I need those to stay in queue. Also at runtime I don't know about what calls are triggered at which time, because this is all user action dependend. So I can't call the `check` request after the `save` request, because I have no idea if the user triggered an action that need to call the `check` request.

So I need a global implementation, where ajax requests always wait for their execution until every request that pre existed has finished.

So I want those calls to be async (to not freeze the UI, etc) but "sync" in regards of their execution order.

Comment: Yes. Set up the next request in the callback of the first.

Comment: it is because of the asynchronous nature of ajax request...

Comment: Use the `promises` returned from ajax calls. You can run any number in parallel or sequentially or in combinations as required. *Using callbacks will introduce dependencies in the code you may not want.*

Comment: As the updated version and a comment below Praveen Kumars answer suggests: I basically want a request to check, if there are currently requests running. If not, the request is triggered, if yes, the request should wait until all other are finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a very usefull jquery plugin [ajaxQ](http://foliotek.github.io/AjaxQ/) that allows you to create a queue of ajax requests

```
$.ajaxq ("MyQueue", {
    url: 'http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "jsonp"
});
```

In my opinion it is best to create an add-to-queue function for yourself, like so:

```
function AddRequest(name, url, postData) {
var jqXHR = $.ajaxq(name, {
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: postData,
    beforeSend: function () {
        //do stuff
    },
    error: function (response) {
        //do stuff
    },
    complete: function (response) {
        //do stuff
    },
    success: function (response) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
}
```

Then you can call this with:

```
var myurl = "http://www.example.com/myaction";
var postData = "myparam1=one&myparam2=two";
AddRequest('myAjaxQueue', myurl, postData);
```

Comment: this gave me a hard time a few months ago and this solution solved it for me, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery's `$.ajax()` or `$.post()` or `$.get()`, use the call back to start the next one! Eg:

```
console.log("AJAX start: Save Game");
$.post("save-game.php", function(){
    console.log("AJAX finish: Save Game");
    console.log("AJAX start: Check");
    $.post("check.php", function(){
        console.log("AJAX finish: Check");
        // Iterate from here using a recursive function! :P
    });
});
```

You can do the iteration, may be this way:

```
function saveCheckGame()
{
    console.log("AJAX start: Save Game");
    $.post("save-game.php", function(){
        console.log("AJAX finish: Save Game");
        console.log("AJAX start: Check");
        $.post("check.php", function(){
            console.log("AJAX finish: Check");
            saveCheckGame();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I can't do this because the calls are triggered by user interactions. This can be many many different places. So these calls must remain independent.

Comment: @JohannesKlauß So, can you use the `$.ajaxComplete` method to check if the AJAX call is completed and then move on with the next one?

Comment: Not really, because I don't know if there is a next one. I basically want a request to check, if there are currently requests running. If not, the request is triggered, if yes, the request should wait until all other are finished.

Comment: Ah! Grr... I give up. I need to think of a way to do this! :)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the callback of the first request to start the next.

A cleaner solution would be to set up an event in the callback and run the second request when the event is triggered.

In the first request callback

```
$( document ).trigger( "request1Finished" );
```

Attach event handler

```
$( document ).on( "request1Finished", function() {
    // run next request
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call/25501002#25501002) you can find an interesting aspects async ajax calls. But I think you should consider `jQuery .promise()` for your scenario. It has the ability to wait and execute. You can find more details on [docs](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/).

Read [this](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) and [jQuery ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) also. This blog contains a good example on [how to use](http://www.danieldemmel.me/blog/2013/03/22/an-introduction-to-jquery-deferred-slash-promise/) deferred promises.